# Selecting an element that has no class and id using CSS?

Tags: css, selector

I have this HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="...">link</a>
</li>
some text
```

I want to select the "some text" after the li and apply some style on it. Is that possible? The li is inside a div with a class, if thats of any help.

Btw: I cant wrap it in a span or div.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can using css while it's a plain text. Try with javascript

Comment: please, define, "select". Do you mean you want apply a style only to that text? Can you wrap that text in its own selector?

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan: Yes, I want to apply some CSS on that.

Comment: You can wrap your text into `span` and select using `ul > span {}`

Comment: I cant wrap it in anything, I have to use it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Premising that you should modify your markup (it's invalid) and wrap that text in its own element, the only way with the given markup is to apply a style to your `div` element and then revert it on the `li`, e.g. — if you need "some text" in italic you could do

```
div { font-style: italic; }
div li { font-style: normal; }
```